# Mongo DB Join Collections

Tags: mongodb, join, collections

I am pretty new to Mongo db and coming from T-SQL background, I am finding little hard to understand how joins work in Mongo.

I have a very simple case where i have a "User Table.. err.. Collections" and "User Audit Collections"..

My User Collection looks something like this.

```
{
  "_id": LUUID("d991e92a-766c-054e-9ad8-1c902acc6efc"),
  "System": {
    "VisitCount": 1
  },
  "UserData": {
    "Uid": "46831",
    "UserName": "abc.",
    "FirstName": "abv",
    "LastName": "test",
    "EmailId": "abc@gmail.com",
    "Region": "Georgia",
    "Postal": "10000",
    "Country": "United States",
    "Phone": "800-000-1734",
    }
}
```

and a User Audit Table :

```
{
  "_id": LUUID("9561a583-0afe-e844-a090-43ffdab46ed2"),
  "UserId": LUUID("914ed252-3fc7-d84c-9731-f382e7cf400b"),
  "StartDateTime": ISODate("2016-05-12T04:07:37.299Z"),
  "EndDateTime": ISODate("2016-05-12T04:07:42.715Z"),
  "SaveDateTime": ISODate("2016-05-12T04:28:23.186Z"),
  "Browser": {
    "BrowserVersion": "50.0",
    "BrowserMajorName": "Chrome",
    "BrowserMinorName": "50.0"
  },
  "Pages": [
    {
      "DateTime": ISODate("2016-05-12T04:07:37.365Z"),
      "Duration": 5416,
      "Item": {
        "_id": LUUID("f293157a-f22d-fe49-a7b0-f66f412408fe"),
        "Language": "en",
        "Version": 1
      }"Url": {
        "Path": "/"
      },
      "VisitPageIndex": 1
    },
    {
      "DateTime": ISODate("2016-05-12T04:07:42.781Z"),
      "Duration": 0,
      "Item": {
        "Version": 0
      },
      "SitecoreDevice": {
        "_id": LUUID("df7f5dfe-c089-994d-9aa3-b5fbd009c9f3"),
        "Name": "Default"
      },
      "MvTest": {
        "ValueAtExposure": 0
      },
      "Url": {
        "Path": "/Sample Page1"
      },
      "VisitPageIndex": 2
    }
  ]  
}
```

I need a Flat view where each row will hold all the user User information and the pages the user visited.
The Audit information can be grouped by user or repeated per user..  My main idea is to combine the User details with Page visited history.

I am looking for something like a Left outer join equivalent

something like

```
Select * from usertable, useraudittable 
on usertable.id = userAuditTable.UserId
group by userID.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo is a simple object storage database and does not offer a lot of relational operations like joins. Normally you have to do it programmatically doing multiple queries and processing the data using your application code and logic.

In Mongo 3.2 they introduced the lookup operation to the aggregation pipeline and fortunately it kinda does what you are looking for. You can use something like this (using mongo shell javascript syntax as example)

```
db.user.aggregate([{ 
  $lookup: {
      from: "audit",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "UserId",
      as: "VisitedPages"
      }    
}]);
```

If you are using the last version of mongo you can play with this approach otherwise you'll need to go with multiple queries on your application.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Thanks Andre.. i was coincidentally checking the same document and i ran the exact same query.. i am getting back results.. but they are not more than 50. is that a limitation?

Comment: Sorry for taking that long. I've tried your example data locally and I've inserted 67 audit records and got all of them using the aggregation query posted above. I'm not aware of any limitation, specially such a low number like 50. But you may be careful when joining such huge documents together, you'll get some memory and performance issues. You can always limit the fields returned by the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that this is a limitation with GUI.. roboMongo was returning only 50 records. i was able to get the records from Mongobooster and Slamdata..

Comment: One Last question.. How do i select only individual fields rather than selecting all and use  Alias...  Like  { Select Usertable.Id as 'User Id" , Visitcount}

Comment: I don't know if you can limit the fields of the lookup document (audit) but you probably can limit the user fields. Just read a bit about the mongo aggregation framework. You have a $project that let's you limit the fields and even rename them on the pipeline. You should have a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) as one of the first elements of the pipeline to reduce the amount of data flowing through it. Aggregation it's quite big and flexible, but you'll lose some time learning all the tricks.